# In Laravel 4 is there a best practice for subdomain controllers?

Tags: controller, laravel, laravel-4, subdomain

I'm looking for a simple way to take my existing Laravel 4 controllers and models and have them return a json object response when visiting - "api.myapp.com".

Is there a routing filter I can use with a specified subdomain request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered that the problem was 2 things:
1) I forgot to update my local host file to resolve the subdomain correctly.
2) Laravel 4 Route::resource instances cannot be reused in multiple Route::group().

I found the only way to reference the same resource routes on different subdomains is to specify each RESTful route manually and creating a new controller for each resource. Jeffery Way has a nice sublime snippet to speed this up. [Snippet here.](https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/3717337)

Note the "Api.." before each copied controller, which is named the same in my controllers directory.

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'www.myapp.com'), function()
{
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');
});

Route::group(array('domain' => 'api.myapp.com'), function()
{

/ Resource API
// project API Resource
    Route::get('projects', array('as' => 'projects', 'uses' => 'ApiProjectsController@index'));
    Route::get('projects/{id}', array('as' => 'project', 'uses' => 'ApiProjectsController@show'));
    Route::get('projects/new', array('as' => 'new_project', 'uses' => 'ApiProjectsController@new'));
    Route::get('projects/{id}/edit', array('as' => 'edit_project', 'uses' => 'ApiProjectsController@edit'));
    Route::post('projects', 'ApiProjectsController@create');
    Route::put('projects/{id}', 'ApiProjectsController@update');
    Route::delete('projects/{id}', 'ApiProjectsController@destroy');
});
```

The next step is to then call the appropriate response in the ApiProjectController RESTful methods.

Comment: Also, don't forget to substitute the ":any" wildcards to something like "{id}" in Jeffery's resource snippet. It was made for L3.

Comment: Also worth noting that this was tested with the Laravel 4.0.* BETA-3. This may be resolved in BETA-4.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a before filter - and check for the 'api' subdomain. Something like this

```
Route::filter('before', function()
{
    $server = explode('.', Request::server('HTTP_HOST'));
    if ($server[0] === 'api')
    {
         // Api subdomain request - do JSON
    }
    else
    {
         // Route normal
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up discovering that my DNS settings were the problem. I can use the "Route::group(array("domain" => "api.myapp.com")..." I'm posting more details below.